# How do I get the current fee to sign a tx from an on-chain program?

Tags: rust

Previously, one could use the [`Fees` Sysvar](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/sysvar/fees.rs.html#20), however this has been deprecated since 1.9. What is the current best practice for getting the current cost of a tx on-chain without an external oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Fees` sysvar was deprecated because transaction fees will not be deterministic anymore. Originally they were calculated based on the amount of signatures required to complete the transaction.

Now transaction fees are based on signatures provided + an additional fee provided in the transaction for prioritization on the cluster.

They may also include [write-lock fees](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/21883) in the future, making the fees non-deterministic which cannot be accessed on-chain.